# Recent posts show thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, sidebar, recent-posts

I'm learning wordpress theme development and using Underscores as my starter theme. How can I show either a small thumbnail of a image or featured image, from each post In my recent posts custom widget. Thank everyone.

Comment: Have you done any research on the matter? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried to use <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>?